# Most efficient way to render a textured cube in pyglet/opengl

Tags: python, opengl, pyglet

Currently, I have this code, which renders a textured cube. It works just fine with a few cubes, but when I add hundreds, it takes forever to create.

```
def get_tex(file):
    tex = pyglet.image.load(file).get_texture()
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
    return pyglet.graphics.TextureGroup(tex)


def make_textures(textures):
    result = {}
    base = "imgs/"
    faces = ("left", "right", "top", "bottom", "front", "back")
    for face in faces:
        file_name = textures.get(face, textures.get("side"))
        result[face] = get_tex(base + file_name)
    return result

def get_vertices(x, y, z):
    dx, dy, dz = x + 1, y + 1, z + 1
    return [
        (x, y, z, x, y, dz, x, dy, dz, x, dy, z),  # side
        (dx, y, dz, dx, y, z, dx, dy, z, dx, dy, dz),  # side
        (x, dy, dz, dx, dy, dz, dx, dy, z, x, dy, z),  # top
        (x, y, z, dx, y, z, dx, y, dz, x, y, dz),  # bottom
        (dx, y, z, x, y, z, x, dy, z, dx, dy, z),  # side
        (x, y, dz, dx, y, dz, dx, dy, dz, x, dy, dz),  # side
    ]
class Grass:
    textures = make_textures({"side": "grass_side.png", "top": "grass_top.png", "bottom": "dirt.png"})


   
def draw_block(self, block):

    position = (block.x,block.y,block.z)
    if block._type == "grass":
        block = Grass
    else:
        block = Grass
    vertices = get_vertices(*position)
    faces = ("left", "right", "top", "bottom", "front", "back")
    for vertex, face in zip(vertices, faces):
        self.batch.add(
            4,
            gl.GL_QUADS,
            block.textures[face],
            ("v3f/static", vertex),
            ("t2f/static", (0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1)),
        )
```

But this takes way too long to create and I can't use another thread to do this because I am calling gl functions.

Comment: Not sure the function name corresponds with what it does. But don't do `draw_block` on each render frame. I hope/assume you know this already.